# multiple WHERE query

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a news feed page like in Facebook, Twitter, or any other social media sites out there.

My problem is I need to get all the user id's of each user's friends, then use all those values to query another table that has all the new updates.

So, let's say I have 3 friends (1,2,3). I want to search another table using all 3 values in my WHERE clause in the same query so that I can order it by date.

The way I've done it so far puts all the id's into an array and uses a foreach loop to query my db for every value I have, but this groups all the results based on the order of user id in the array, so my results come out like this 11111,222222,333333 instead of the time the update was made. So, even if 3 makes an update days before 1 or 2, it will always come after two.

I am aware this might not be the best way to do it, but so far it's the only method I can think of.

Please any assistance you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

My code:

```
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$update = mysql_query("
    SELECT profile_id FROM `fiends` 
    WHERE `my_fiend_id` = '$id'
    ");
$result = $update;
$fiends = array();

while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) !== false) {
    $fiends[] = array(
        'id' => $row['profile_id'],
);}

foreach($fiends as $fiend) {
    $fiend_id = $fiend['id'];
    $update_select = mysql_query("          
        SELECT * FROM `update` 
        WHERE `NU_id` = '$fiend_id'                 
        ORDER BY `time` DESC
        ");

$result = $update_select;
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Your code actually makes no sense. You should look into using a `JOIN`.

Answer (score 4):

You should turn this into one query

```
SELECT `update`.*
FROM `update`
INNER JOIN `fiends` ON update.`NU_id` = fiends.`my_fiend_id`
WHERE `my_fiend_id` = '$id'              
ORDER BY `time` DESC
```

Alternatively, you can use an `IN ()` statement

```
"SELECT * FROM `update` WHERE `NU_id` = IN ('".join(',', $fiend_id)."')"
```

Your final statement would look something like this

```
WHERE `NU_id` IN (11111,222222,333333)
```

If the `NU_ID` is a varchar column then make sure to use quotes around the values

```
WHERE `NU_id` IN ('11111','222222','333333)
```

Comment: Using IN instead of JOIN is a lot more slower. You and everybody else will notice that once their data starts growing.

Comment: @YasenZhelev that's why I showed the join first. This user didn't know about either option from what I can tell and know they'll know how to use both.

Comment: I meant MySQL JOIN, not joining the friend IDs. edit: I see your change in the answer now :) Do not forget the order bit ;)

Comment: thanks a lot for the answers it wasn't exactly what i was looking for but because of it i was able learn what i needed i ended up using the IN and imploding the array into the WHERE claws so it looks like this SELECT * FROM `update` 
WHERE `NU_id` IN (".implode(" ,",$my_friends_id).")

Answer (score 0):

I would recommed you use an inner join on the SQL query instead of using a PHP loop. MySQL is faster, than a PHP loop.

Try this simpler version first

```
SELECT friends.profile_id, update.* 
FROM `fiends`, `update` 
WHERE `my_fiend_id` = '$id'
AND `NU_id` = `my_fiend_id`                 
ORDER BY `time` DESC
```

Comment: please, please, please scope your column names. Using `AND NU_id = my_fiend_id` is going to create some horrible habits and cause headaches for developers looking at your code.

Comment: Yeah, it was just a quick copy/past. It could be improved in many ways.